# Beginner's PHP question -- ":" in a multidimensional array

Tags: php

I'm trying to access information in a previously created multidimensional array. Using `print_r()`, I've got this info about the array(which I've spaced out myself, and may've done so oddly...):

```
    Array ( 
    [Video] => Array ( 
        [0] => a:3:{
            s:19:"upload_video_submit";
            s:0:"";
            s:12:"upload_video";
            s:26:"this-is-the-video-link.mp4";
            s:12:"video_length";
            s:8:"10-10-10";
            } 
    ) 
    [_edit_last] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) 
    [_edit_lock] => Array ( [0] => 1288823181 )
    [key] => Array ( 
        [0] => a:4:{
            s:4:"game";
            a:2:{
                i:0;
                s:4:"9man";
                i:1;
                s:5:"18man";
                }
            s:4:"type";
            a:1:{
                i:0;
                s:7:"Lecture";
                }
            s:5:"coach";
            a:1:{
                i:0;
                s:8:"msusyr24";
                }
            s:12:"upload-video";
            s:70:"http://localhost:8888/pocarr/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/BigCupcake.flv";
            } 
            ) 
    )
```

I'd like to access the arrays inside the key array, such something like 
`echo $key_array[key][0]["type"]` to get "Lecture", or `echo $key_array[Video][0]["upload_video"]` to get "this-is-the-videolink.mp4" ... but I'm totally baffled by the ":"s

The most I can figure is that "s" = a string, and the number is the number of characters (similarly "a"= an array).

Any ideas how to get that info out of the array?

**UPDATE:**
I ended up using:

```
$new = unserialize($keys_array[Video][0]);
echo $new[upload_video];
```

Thanks for you help!

Comment: please, try `var_dump($you_array)` instead `print_r($yoy_array)` and post output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like some of your array values have been serialized. Check out PHP's [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function. Doing so will allow you to access the array elements as you describe.

For example:

```
print_r(unserialize($key_array[Video][0]));
```

Answer (score 3):

The array elements are serialized. Unserialize them, and they'll be a lot easier to access.

```
$videoArray = unserialize($myArray['Video'][0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

And one more thing:

if you want to format your echo code try next time with

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use unserialize($object);